# How to solve for node voltages using mesh analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, mesh-analysis

I am given the following circuit to analyze:
[image]

The problem asks me to solve for the unknown currents and then find the node voltages at N1 and N2.
Here are the mesh equations I came up with:
$$Mesh1$$
$$24000i_1-20000i_2-4000i_3=20$$
$$Mesh2$$
$$-20000i_1+22200i_2-200i_3=0$$
$$Mesh3$$
$$-4000i_1-200i_2+610i_3=0$$

Solving for the system of equations, I get the following:
[image: Wolfram alpha solution of mesh equations]

The thing I'm stuck with now is calculating the node voltages N1 and N2. Do I calculate the individual voltage drops on the resistors first?

Comment: Yes, and you then work from the known voltage (20 V) at the V2/R6/R8 node.

Comment: @Chu I just subtract the voltage drops from 20V right?

Comment: e.g. if the voltage across R6 is, say, 5 V, with the polarity (+) on its left and (-) on its right (+ sign where the current enters the resistor), then N1 voltage is: 20-5 = 15 V. A neat way of doing this, generally, is: start from ground and do what the polarities tell you as you travel to your destination (node N1 in this case), thus: 0V at ground, then go up in voltage through the battery (0 +20 = 20V), then go down in voltage through R6 (20-5 = 15V). You can go on any path to the destination.

Comment: ... btw, your current calculations aren't correct; i1  is the source current and must be +ve in this circuit as it's the only source, (assuming this is a complete circuit diagram and there isn't a V1 lurking somewhere!)

Comment: I would quickly like to say that this is how homework questions *should* be asked on this site. It is the second one by OP, and both questions have shown clear effort, OP has shared their attempt, and reading through comments has a willingness to learn and understand where they went wrong. +1 from me!

Comment: @Chu thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

It's often best to redraw the schematic. Sometimes, this works well in your favor. This is an unbalanced wheatstone bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXzRRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This would be very easy with nodal. But you want mesh. So:

$$\begin{align*}
20\:\text{V}-\left(I_1+I_3\right)\cdot R_8-\left(I_1+I_2\right)\cdot R_7-I_1\cdot R_6&=20\:\text{V}\\\\
0\:\text{V}-\left(I_2-I_3\right)\cdot R_9-\left(I_1+I_2\right)\cdot R_7-I_2\cdot R_{10}&=0\:\text{V}\\\\
20\:\text{V}-\left(I_1+I_3\right)\cdot R_8-\left(I_3-I_2\right)\cdot R_9&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

You should be able to solve for \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$, and \$I_3\$ with ease.

Once you have the currents, it's very easy to solve for \$V_x\$ and \$V_y\$. For example, \$V_x=20\:\text{V}-\left(I_1+I_3\right)\cdot R_8\$.

---

Should you have wanted nodal, then it would be these:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_x}{R_7}+\frac{V_x}{R_8}+\frac{V_x}{R_9}&=\frac{V_y}{R_7}+\frac{20\:\text{V}}{R_8}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_9}\\\\
\frac{V_y}{R_6}+\frac{V_y}{R_7}+\frac{V_y}{R_{10}}&=\frac{20\:\text{V}}{R_6}+\frac{V_x}{R_7}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_{10}}
\end{align*}$$

Here, you'd solve for just two voltages. And from there, you could get the currents if you wanted them.

Either way works.

Comment: Just a question, are my mesh calculations correct?

Comment: @Augue, No, they don't appear to be correct to me. Compare them and see what you think.

Comment: Ok. Using your approach, I got Vx as 2.71V. Simulations show that Vx is 0.29V.

Comment: @AugieJavax98, using nodal, I get Vx as .291. How do you get your value??

Comment: @AugieJavax98 For example, \$V_x=0.291116727511\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_y=0.1085837312\:\text{V}\$. That's what I get with the nodal equations, anyway.

Comment: I did my calculations again and got the correct answers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AugieJavax98 No problem. You may either select my answer (checking it), which will suggest to others that there's no longer a need for another answer; or else leave it open for others to reply (perhaps better.) I think you get points for checking answers (not many, but a few) if you care about that.